# with git, how do i compartmentalize part of aproject

Tags: git

i'm new to git - and trying to see how i can improve my work flow.

there are three locations of note:

1. the main repo that i keep in the cloud - which holds everything as backup
2. my local environment where i do work
3. a location on the cloud for others to only see the finished parts

how can i ensure that everything is backed up on to `1` and only the things i want shared are in `3`?

i know that repos hold all history, so i don't just want to clone `1` into `3`.  i was thinking of making the `FINISHED` directory a submodule, but not sure if `3` should then be a master that i clone from and then push to...

what is the most efficient way of doing this?

```
1:.
├───.git
├───WORK_IN_PROGRESS
│   ├───.txt
│   └───.sql
│   └───.py
│   └───.csv
│   └───.blah
├───FINISHED
│   └───.git
│   └───.sql
│   └───.py
```

```
3:.
├───FINISHED
│   └───.git
│   └───.sql
│   └───.py
```

Comment: "i was thinking of making the FINISHED directory a submodule" In your diagram it is _already_ a submodule.

Comment: @matt i just threw that in there as an example

Comment: Right, but if you're happy with that, it's hard to see what the question is. It's not what I would do, if I can avoid it, but really everything depends on the nature of your project and what the relationship is between the development project and the Finished folder. These could simply be different branches of on local repo. Or they could be totally separate local repos (ie not inside each other).

Comment: @matt i mean, i'm looking for the best strategy whereby i can share only parts of my work.  for example..maybe it would be better to make `3` the master for each project file, clone them into `1` and then clone that into my local at `2` and push upwards?

Comment: But I just told you it depends what "share" and "work" mean. For example this https://github.com/mattneub/understandingCombine is the source of this https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/ but they aren't kept in the same repo. In fact the second isn't in any repo at all; it's the product and doesn't need versioning.

Comment: @matt ok im a bit of a noob here, so have to apologize for misunderstanding.  my idea is, the finished folder will contain work that i have done which will not be used by anyone else - but may be edited by someone.   in which case, i would like to be able to pull it back to my working environment, so that i can work on it some more.  no need for anyone to see my notes etc, just clean code that wont confuse them.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using branches? Work in the feature branch and merge your finished work into the "Finished" branch. And send only the finished branch to the cloud.

Comment: is there anyway you can draw this out for me like i'm 5?

Comment: Your thinking is almost correct. Just replace the directories with branches in your algorithm. Do not store files in different directories. Keep them in different branches. The files will be in the single directory of your project.

Comment: And please read the [Git manual](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)

Comment: Or any [another tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches)

Comment: You can't work in Git without understanding the simple concepts. A step-by-step tutorial won't help you. Git is easy, but you have to understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

The Git answer to this question is "you don't".

Seriously, that's pretty much it.  Git doesn't "do" compartmentalization: the repository is whole unto itself.  Each clone of the repository is a full copy of everything.  Everyone has full access to every file.  Every commit stores every file.  History consists of nothing *but* commits, and every commit is read-only, frozen in time forever: you only *add new commits*.  If something is wrong somewhere, you *add another commit*.  That's it!  That's the end of the story.

[Of course, like all simple and neat answers, it's wrong.](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2016/07/17/solution/)  Wrong here means *not what people want*, rather than *incorrect*, although this description is in fact incomplete—in part because people, being people, have added things *to* Git to make it do what they want:

- *Shallow* clones are those that omit some history.
- *Partial* clones—a still-new-ish feature that has a lot of sharp edges—are those that omit some *objects* so that the clone goes a lot faster initially and is much smaller, but they don't have all the history: they retrieve it on demand (and currently very poorly so).
- *Submodules*, which many call *sob*-modules because that's what they make people do when they use them, allow specific commits within a specific repository refer to other commits (by the commits' unique hash IDs) in other repositories.

These pieces can be used, in various fashions and with various limitations, to achieve the kind of compartmentalization you're talking about.  But for the most part, if it's not absolutely required by some sort of external constraint, *don't do it*.  [You will regret it.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NGU8LDO)